# Why do register machines outperform stack machines?

Tags: automata, computer-architecture

[Wikipedia says](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_machine) stack machine “designs have though been routinely outperformed by the traditional register machine systems, and have remained a niche player in the market.” Why is this?

Comment: Have you read the section *Performance disadvantages of stack machines* in the Wikipedia article?

Comment: (When the *Novix N4016* hit the market, its speed compared favourably to competitors. I put that to a) being new b) a "dual access memory interface", costing pins&power, increasing component and, more importantly, system cost.)

Answer (score 3):

I think the prime reason why **register** machines are better at performance because **registers** are within the **CPU** chip itself, however stack is generally the part of main memory, accessing register is on average **1-3** clock cycles, **level 1 cache** requires nearly **10-20 cycles** on average, and depending on the design it could have **level 2 shared cache** which takes about **40 cycles** on average, finally main memory takes **100s** of cycles in comparison per initial word access then once you access it, the further block containing the required word is only incrementally cycle consuming. Hence register based architecture should always out perform stack based.

> The data presented is definitely not according to today's state of the art processors take it from more of a conceptual stand point rather than practical one, and that I believe was the intent of the question.

Edit : I came across one more important reason why stack machines are not as efficient as register based microarchitectures, consider the following image [image]

the expression evaluation algorithm is compared between both stack based and register based microarchitectures, observe how variables `a` and `c` are pushed twice. The context here being, the stack based microarchitecture is implemented using a register stack, a memory based would have been far worse in terms of cpu cycles, so even the register implementation of stack based machine still performs worse than plain register based machine, due to multiple push and pops of the same variable and this is an example of a bad architectural design, where the ISA only allows stack based operations.

Comment: `accessing [a CPU] register is on average 5-10 clock cycles` - can you substantiate this?

Comment: Any modern CPU can access a CPU register in a single clock cycle, and do something useful with it to boot. Increasing the Instructions Per Clock is how CPU's got faster in the last decade, even though CPU frequencies have hovered around the 3 Ghz mark.

Answer (score 2):

Stack machines have a specialized hardware architecture, which is ideal for some problems. For the vast majority of algorithms, it's not optimal. For instance, take sorting. With random access, sorting is ideally done with a variation of the common quicksort algorithm. With a single stack, you have a problem even *sorting* the stack - the vast majority of input permutations [can't even be sorted!](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack-sortable_permutation)

Now real-world stack machines are a bit more flexible, but as soon as you design an architecture that allows O(1) access to the top N values of the stack, it starts to morph into an N-register CPU. Sure, you get some fancy register shuffling as the stack is pushed and popped, but modern register-oriented CPU's can do far more flexible register renaming. on the fly.